# How to import data into the app using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my phone's Storage, There is a file which is "**MyFile.sql**". There are **200 records** at the file. What should I do is to import those 200 records into the app.

**First, I just Initialize**

```
 llUpdate.setOnClickListener { UpgradeDB(txtUpdate!!).execute("", "", "") }
```

After that, I start a **method**, I don't know why It found the file and read already, But it doesn't import to the app. Is this because I write `return = null` So it didn't import to the app?

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String? {
                val filename = "MyFile.sql"
                val sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                val file = File(sdcard, filename)

                if (!file.exists()) isCancelled

                var dbHelper: MyDBHelper? = null
                dbHelper?.writableDatabase.use { db ->
                    var intTotalLine = 0
                    var intLine = 1
                    BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).useLines { _ -> intTotalLine++ }
                    BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).use { r ->
                        r.lineSequence().forEach {
                            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                db?.execSQL(it)
                                publishProgress(String.format("Updating %s/%s records", intLine, intTotalLine))
                                intLine++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null

        }
```

Can you guys Please Help me to check where are the mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What directory is the file stored in? Why not add some print statements or breakpoints so you can see what it happening?

Comment: Can I have some example? I tried to put breakpoint at the `dbHelper?.writableDatabase.use { db ->`, It will loop until it says "Updating 200/1", Then jump to `return null`. No errors, So I don't know where should I fix. @EamonScullion

Comment: try change `if` to `while` and see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize database using kotlin in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476189/initialize-database-using-kotlin-in-asynctask)