# Initialize database using kotlin in AsyncTask

Tags: android, kotlin

In my `doInBackground` I declare and Initialize db, I got an error which say type mismatch. What should I put instead of putting `this`?

```
var dbHelper: MyDBHelper? = null
dbHelper = MyDBHelper(this)
```

What should I put, There say `Required: Context!`

And this is my async task code, That Problem at `dbHelper = MyDBHelper(this)`.

```
private class UpgradeDB(textView: TextView?) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        var innerTextView: TextView? = textView

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            innerTextView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String? {
            val filename = "eBOSSInv_Upgrade.sql"
            val sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            val file = File(sdcard, filename)

            if (!file.exists()) isCancelled

            try {
                var dbHelper: MyDBHelper? = null

                dbHelper = MyDBHelper(this)

                dbHelper!!.writableDatabase.use { db ->
                    var intTotalLine = 0
                    var intLine = 1
                    BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).useLines { _ -> intTotalLine++ }
                    BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).use { r ->
                        r.lineSequence().forEach {
                            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                db!!.execSQL(it)
                                publishProgress(String.format("Updating %s/%s records", intLine, intTotalLine))
                                intLine++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
            return null
        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String) {
            innerTextView!!.text = text[0]
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            innerTextView!!.text = ""
        }

        override fun onCancelled() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: "MainActivity@this" like this

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all relevant code. What is `this` here? Where is the AsyncTask located? Do you really need to declare the database inside the AsyncTask?

Comment: Sorry this may sound a bit blunt, but maybe you should focus on understanding Android before you go about working with Kotlin also, which looks like you haven't worked with much (looking at the code). You have quite a lot of issues in the Android code, that are not specific to Kotlin and if you don't know what `this` is in this case, then I guess you haven't even written the code in the first place. I think you're digging in too deep into areas that you don't fully understand yet. Depending on what `this` is here it looks like you could end up with a memory leak for instance.

Comment: problem fixed. Thank you guys~

Comment: Noted, But Those code was done by previous employee, It caused me a lot of problems. @Darwind

Comment: @lowzaii then maybe you should rewrite it, instead of trying to remedying it with Kotlin? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `context` into `Async Task`.

Example:

```
llUpdate.setOnClickListener { 
       UpgradeDB(txtUpdate!!, getApplication()).execute("", "", "") 
}
```

Then in `UpgradeDB`, initialize the context.

```
private class UpgradeDB(textView: TextView?, context: Context) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        var innerTextView: TextView? = textView
        var mContext:Context? = context // initialize context
    }
```

And finally

```
dbHelper = MyDBHelper(mContext)
```

Comment: @lowzaii my pleasure

Comment: While this will solve the problem I think you should mention that this might cause issues, as you leave a `Context` hanging around in an `AsyncTask` that potentially doesn't finish before the `Context` is gone. What issues might this cause?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you try to create this object. Unless you do it in a class that extends Context (like Activity) it is not supposed to work. You can try such construct:

There are two ways you gan go:

The simpler way: Declare your AsyncTask as inner class inside tour activity and reference context using label. To declare class as inner you need to place it inside another class and add *inner* keyowrd:

```
class A {

    inner class B

}
```

Now you can reference context from inside your async task like that:

```
dbHelper = DbHelper([ActivityName]@this)
```

Nevertheless, this is easy way to cause a memory leak, you can read more here: [Android AsyncTask memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273753/android-asynctask-memory-leaks)

The better way is to extract AsyncTask to another class and pass an application context to it, instead of Activity.

Comment: I'm using this `dbHelper = MyBDHelper([MainDBAdminActivity]@this)`, It's doesn't work.

Comment: @lowzaii could you please show your activity and async task code?

Comment: can you open a chat room ? @Michal Powloka

Comment: @lowzaii Not really. You'd do best if you add it to your question, as mentioned in comment. If you cannot share actual code you can just include important parts or write simmilar example.

Comment: @lowzaii Tanks. Try making UpgradeDb inner class, by decalring it:

private inner class UpgradeDb.

Then, you can reference activity from inside using [MainDBAdminActivity]@this